# Equation of a plane in normal form

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d, alternative-proof

There is a standard derivation of the equation of a plane, when the following quantities are given

$1.)$ A vector normal to the plane, from the origin $:$ $\vec{ON}$ $=$ $d{ô}$, where $d$ is some real number, and $d≠0$

$ô$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{ON}$

$2.)$ An arbitrary point $P$ on the plane with the position vector $\vec{r}$

We know that $\vec{ON}.\vec{NP}=0$

From this follows: $(\vec{r}-dô).dô=0$

In my textbook, after solving this equation, it is shown that since $(\vec{r}-dô).dô=0$

$(\vec{r}-dô).ô=0$

$\vec{r}ô-d=0$

$\vec{r}ô= d$

I was wondering about any other approach from the equation $(\vec{r}-dô).dô=0$  to get an equation that is equivalent of the equation $\vec{r}.ô=d$

I tried in the following manner

$\vec{r}.dô-dô.dô=0$

$\vec{r}.dô-d^2=0$

$\vec{r}.dô=d^2$

How is this equation related to $\vec{r}ô= d$

We can also state that how to prove that $(\vec{r}.dô)=(\vec{r}.ô)d$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation correctly, $d$ is just some real number. The inner product you are using in order to express orthogonality is what one calls bilinear, i.e. (using your (non-standard) notation) $$(a \vec{v}_1+b \vec{v}_2).\vec{v}_3 = a(\vec{v}_1.\vec{v}_3)+b(\vec{v}_2.\vec{v}_3)$$
for any choice of vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. So coming back your first question, one has

$$ \vec{r}.dô=d^2 \Leftrightarrow d(\vec{r}.ô) = d^2 \Leftrightarrow \vec{r}.ô = d,$$
which is your original equation. Using above notion of bilinearity, I think you can figure out the answer to your second question by yourself.